# Why can't I set the colspan of this element using .colspan?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

From What I understand in JavaScript any attribute can be set with `element.attribute = newValue`. So I'm trying to set the colspan of multiple table cells with `element.colspan = 2` yet it doesn't work. Any suggestions are appreciated. My code is below.

```css
table td, table th{ border: 2px solid #0f0f0f; text-align:center; }

.noDisplay{ display:none; }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
     <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr class = "dateCells" ><td colspan = "1">DATE</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cell One</td><td class = "cells noDisplay">Cell Two</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cell One</td><td class = "cells noDisplay">Cell Two</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cell One</td><td class = "cells noDisplay">Cell Two</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cell One</td><td class = "cells noDisplay">Cell Two</td></tr>

          <tr class = "dateCells" ><td colspan = "1">DATE</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cell One</td><td class = "cells noDisplay">Cell Two</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cell One</td><td class = "cells noDisplay">Cell Two</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cell One</td><td class = "cells noDisplay">Cell Two</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cell One</td><td class = "cells noDisplay">Cell Two</td></tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
    <br>
    <div onclick = "clicked()">CLICK<br>HERE</div>

    <script>
      function clicked(){
          var cells = document.getElementsByClassName( 'cells' );

          for( var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++ ){
            cells[ i ].classList.remove( 'noDisplay' );
          }

          var dateCells = document.getElementsByClassName( 'dateCells' );

          for( var i = 0; i < dateCells.length; i++ ){
            dateCells[ i ].colspan = 2;
          }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see above, for some reason the colspan of the `dateCells` elements aren't changing from 1 to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you were adding it to the tr elem, notice I've changed the top one only to the td and it expands, also the capital S in colSpan

```js
function clicked(){
  
          var cells = document.getElementsByClassName( 'cells' );

          for( var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++ ){
            cells[ i ].classList.remove( 'noDisplay' );
          }

          var dateCells = document.getElementsByClassName( 'dateCells' );

          for( var r = 0; r < dateCells.length; r++ ){
            dateCells[ r ].colSpan = "2";
          }
      }
```

```css
table td, table th{ border: 2px solid #0f0f0f; text-align:center; }

.noDisplay{ display:none; }
```

```html
     <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr  ><td colspan = "1"class = "dateCells">DATE</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cell One</td><td class = "cells noDisplay">Cell Two</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cell One</td><td class = "cells noDisplay">Cell Two</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cell One</td><td class = "cells noDisplay">Cell Two</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cell One</td><td class = "cells noDisplay">Cell Two</td></tr>

          <tr class = "dateCells" ><td colspan = "1">DATE</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cell One</td><td class = "cells noDisplay">Cell Two</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cell One</td><td class = "cells noDisplay">Cell Two</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cell One</td><td class = "cells noDisplay">Cell Two</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cell One</td><td class = "cells noDisplay">Cell Two</td></tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
    <br>
    <div onclick = "clicked()">CLICK<br>HERE</div>
```

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part. Thanks. Have alot on my mind!

Answer (score 1):

You need `.colSpan` in your script. Notice the capital `S`. Also, instead of having your `dateClass` for your table row `<tr>` you need it in

```
<td class="dateCells" colspan = "1">Date</td>
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1jLse4w5/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
dateCells[ i ].colSpan = "2";
```